# Cooking my own meals in Fajardo Puerto Rico

Tags: food-and-drink, accommodation, puerto-rico

I'm planning for a trip to Puerto Rico for about 6 days. I will probably stay in Fajardo most of the time. What is the best accommodation that has a kitchen so that I can cook my meals? Also are the seafood markets in Fajardo good? I've been googling about this but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @pnuts yes only platanos would be monotonic after a short time.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest renting a room with Airbnb. Very often hosts allow guests to use the kitchen. This is usually specified in the listing description. A quick search for Fajardo reveals 500+ rental offers (rooms and apartments) meaning you have plenty of choice location-wise.

As a corollary to this idea you could rent a full flat thus having the guarantee of a kitchen at your disposal. This of course might be a more expensive solution.

Answer (score 3):

According to hostels.com and hostelworld.com, there is at least one hostel in Fajardo, Puerto Rico, called the [Moon Bay hostel](http://moonlightbayhostel.com/facilities/). Their list of facilities includes "Full kitchen with brand new appliances!" so with little doubt you can buy your own food and cook it at the hostel. I haven't seen any picture of the kitchen among the [pictures](http://moonlightbayhostel.com/pictures/) shown though, just a mention of it in reviews.

The [reviews](http://www.hostelworld.com/hosteldetails.php/Moon-Light-Bay-Hostel/Fajardo/71341/reviews) about this place are interesting. The hostel is actually located near the ferry terminal, but not close to town - and therefore not close to food markets. I'd recommend you to read these reviews before going there.

I did not really understand your second question, however: are you asking if the food sold in seafood markets is edible, or good like recommended gourmet good? In both cases, I would say that if there are running businesses, people buy - and eat - the food. So it is "good".